# Paragraph numbers changing HTML JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, paragraph

I'm working with list which elements can be added with JS by the following code:

```
function getMovementButtons(size, articleId, articleTitle, articleType){
   var lowerArticleType = articleType.toLowerCase();
   var html = '<div>'+
                  '<span style="vertical-align: top">'+ size + 
                      '<span style="vertical-align: top">.</span> '+
                  '</span>'+
                  '<span style="vertical-align: top" class="'+lowerArticleType+'-title displaying-'+lowerArticleType+'-id' + articleId +'">' + articleTitle + '</span>' + 
                  '<input class="'+lowerArticleType+'-button-delete"  type="button" value="' + '<%= LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "global.action.delete")%>' + '" onclick="removeArticle(this,\''+articleType+'\')"/>' +
                  '<div class="'+lowerArticleType+'-div-move"><input class="'+lowerArticleType+'-button-up" type="button" value="" onclick="moveArticleUp(this,\''+articleType+'\')"/>' + 
                      '<input class="'+lowerArticleType+'-button-down" type="button" value="" onclick="moveArticleDown(this,\''+articleType+'\')"/>' + 
                  '</div>'+
              '</div>';
    return html;
```

I have a function removeArticleLine.

```
function removeArticleLine(button) {
    var parentDiv = button.parentNode
    var articleListDiv = parentDiv.parentNode;
    articleListDiv.removeChild(parentDiv);
}
```

There is a problem, because if I delete an object paragraphs don't change their numbers. I would ask you to give me a hint how can I change these numbers with JS. 
I'm adding working functions which can help us. It's moving everything properly:

```
function moveArticleUp(button, articleType) {
    var articleDiv = button.parentNode.parentNode;

    var parentDiv = articleDiv.parentNode;
    var prevArticleDiv = articleDiv.previousElementSibling;

    if (prevArticleDiv && prevArticleDiv.tagName == 'DIV') {
        var articleIdValue = getArticleIdValue(articleType);
        var ids = articleIdValue.split(',');
        var articleId = getArticleIdFromArticleDiv(articleDiv, articleType);
        var articleIdIndex = ids.indexOf(articleId);
        swapPosition(ids, articleIdIndex, articleIdIndex - 1);
        setArticleIdValue(articleType, ids.join());

        removedArticleDiv = parentDiv.removeChild(articleDiv);
        parentDiv.insertBefore(removedArticleDiv, prevArticleDiv);
        console.log(articleIdIndex);
        prevArticleDiv.firstElementChild.innerHTML = articleIdIndex + 1 + '<span style="vertical-align: top">.</span>  ';
        articleDiv.firstElementChild.innerHTML = articleIdIndex + '<span style="vertical-align: top">.</span>  ';
    }
}


function moveArticleDown(button, articleType) {
    var articleDiv = button.parentNode.parentNode;

    var parentDiv = articleDiv.parentNode;
    var nextArticleDiv = articleDiv.nextElementSibling;

    if (nextArticleDiv) {
        var articleIdValue = getArticleIdValue(articleType);
        console.log(articleIdValue);
        var ids = articleIdValue.split(',');
        var articleId = getArticleIdFromArticleDiv(articleDiv, articleType);
        console.log(articleId);
        var articleIdIndex = ids.indexOf(articleId);
        console.log(articleIdIndex);
        swapPosition(ids, articleIdIndex, articleIdIndex + 1);
        setArticleIdValue(articleType, ids.join());
        console.log(ids.join());

        removedArticleDiv = parentDiv.removeChild(nextArticleDiv);
        parentDiv.insertBefore(removedArticleDiv, articleDiv);
        console.log(nextArticleDiv.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
        console.log(articleDiv.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
        nextArticleDiv.firstElementChild.innerHTML = articleIdIndex + 1 + '<span style="vertical-align: top">.</span>  ';
        articleDiv.firstElementChild.innerHTML = articleIdIndex + 2 + '<span style="vertical-align: top">.</span>  ';
    }
}
```

Let me add two screenshots of the displayed table:

[http://imgur.com/a/EOfkk](https://imgur.com/a/EOfkk)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqdKR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

After you remove a line you should loop the array of elements and assign new numbers for them. The code was not tested, but it should works

```
function removeArticleLine(button) {
    var parentDiv = button.parentNode;
    // getting the number of deleting div
    var divNumber = parseInt(parentDiv.firstChild.textContent); 

    var articleListDiv = parentDiv.parentNode;
    articleListDiv.removeChild(parentDiv);

    // we need to loop elements after deleted div, because elements before did not change theit number
    for (var i = 0 || divNumber; i < articleListDiv.children.length; i++) {
       //changing number
       articleListDiv.children[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML = (i + 1) + '<span style="vertical-align: top">.</span> ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't work properly. Do you have an idea how can we write loop for every element and number everything from the beginning?

Comment: yes, just cut divNumber. for (var i = 0; i < articleListDiv.children.length; i++) {